# extending an existing powershell script

Tags: powershell

We currently have a PreDeploy.ps1, Deploy.ps1, PostDeploy.ps1 scripts specific to web applications or window services.  Every once in a while we need to have an extension file to customize the deployment process.

We plan to implement extension files using an underscore - something like:

Deploy.ps1

```
    if( Test-Path "_Deploy.ps1" )
{
    $extensionFile = Resolve-Path "_Deploy.ps1"
    PowerShell -File $extensionFile 
}
```

How can i pass currently scoped variables (variable name and value) to the extensionFile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well don't start a new PowerShell instance. :-)  Run the script in the current PowerShell instance e.g.:

```
& $extensionFile
```

If that $extensionFile needs to modify (or create) variables in the current scope then execute it like so:

```
. $extensionFile
```

Comment: I normally use & to execute external .exe programs and thought i would need powershell.exe - I'll give this a shot.  Thanks!